# 4 USec timer for Initial Sequence Number generation in Linux

Tags: linux

Below are few lines taken from [RFC6528. S3](http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6528.txt)

Proposed Initial Sequence Number Generation Algorithm.

TCP SHOULD generate its Initial Sequence Numbers with the expression:

```
  ISN = M + F(localip, localport, remoteip, remoteport, secretkey)
```

where M is the 4 microsecond timer

What exactly is meant by **4 microsecond timer** ?

(Please do not get deviated from the main focus of the question by the stuff below. This is just to clarify one of my comments)

This  an image which confused me.

[image: MD5 has replaced half MD4 from kernels 3.1, but I'm not sure whether the re-keying is avoided!]

(MD5 has replaced MD4 from kernels 3.1.But I'm not sure whether the re-keying is avoided.
The re-key counter is set to zero on boot, if it is still used)

Comment: A timer which increments every 4ms?

Comment: @rekire: If it is so, the first sequence number generated should be added to a 32 bit value all consisting of zeroes, because the timer is initialised to zero in the beginning. That can't be the case because then the Initial Sequence Number will have only 24 bits in beginning (in the case where both the rekey counter and our timer are both zeroes) ie the first 8 bits of the ISN will be zeroes.

If I'm wrong then the timer must have some other initial value.

Comment: Why 24 bits? I think `F`'s output is 32 bits.

Comment: @ninjalj: Exactly the both M,F() and output M+F() will be four bytes(32 bits) but in the case where the rekey counter and timer M are set to zero(ie 8 0s for RC and 32 0s for M)the most significant 8 bits of the ISN will be set to zero which essentially makes it a 24 bit number and that is not the case..
(I was trying to prove by contradiction that if M is incremented every 4 USecs., its value can't be set to 0 in the beginning )

Comment: I don't see any rekeying required for an implementation of this, and I certainly don't see how that translates to 8 zeroes. You have a function F of 2 16-bit quantities (the ports), 2 32-bit quantities (the IPs), and a key (the RFC recommends at least 128 bits). The RFC recommends MD5 (which again outputs 128 bits). I don't see where do you get that 24 bit restriction from.

Comment: @ninjalj:I believed re-key counter is still used. Please see an edit in the question.

Comment: The picture is from older Linux kernels (e.g: 2.6.27 uses that algorithm). which divide ISNs in two parts, a rekey counter in the upper 8 bits, and the result of the hash in the lower 24 bits, all that added to a 64ns time from the Epoch. RFC6528 has a somewhat different algorithm, which is used on Linux 3.6 (http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/net/core/secure_seq.c#L106), has no rekey, and has no rekey counter on the ISN, so the ISN is 32 bits from the hash added to a 64ns time from the Epoch.

Comment: @ninjalj:So if I have an ISN in the 32 bit long int format how can I do `ISN+(ktime_to_ns(ktime_get_real()) >> 6)` from the user space (from within another C program)

Comment: substirute `ktime_get_real()` with `clock_gettime()`, scale that to nanoseconds, do the shift to get 64ns units. Note: I'm not sure you'll get ns precision in userspace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To avoid trouble from receiving stale segments from an earlier incarnation of a TCP connection, the relevant RFCs suggest a series of measures.

One of the measures is monotically incrementing the ISN at a rate faster than the bandwidth would permit on a live connection, so the next time a connection is opened using the same (source ip, dest ip, source port, dest port) tuple, the sequence number used doesn't coincide with a sequence number used in a TCP segment from the earlier connection.

This and other mechanisms are talked about in the Appendix to [RFC1185](http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1185.txt).

Apparently a 4 µs timer is good for a 2Mb/s network. Linux uses a 64 ns timer.